# retrieving the values for to ng-options from api call

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am a newbie to Angular JS and i have a question with ng-options. it may be silly but please help me sorting this out. I have the following controller which retrieves the country names and values. i want to assign these values to my select box.

```
function AddItemsController($scope, $http, $cookieStore, $location) {
var country_dropdown = "https://pier.com/api/app/dropdown_countries.html?contactid=2951&token=f6aa0dd18a206e40c3f68b154dd00ba0";
$http.get(country_dropdown).success(function(response) {
    console.log(response); // [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
    console.log(response[0].text); // America
    console.log(response[0].value); //13
    });
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
 <span class="ui-select">
  <select id="ai_exchange_member" ng-model="ai_exch_member" required ng-options=""></select>
 </span>
</div>
```

How will i do this rather than adding the static list to the select in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work (assuming you have a model on your scope that holds data):

```
$http.get(country_dropdown).success(function(response) {
    $scope.model.aiExchange.options = response;
}

<select ng-model="model.aiExchange.value" ng-options="opt.text for opt in model.aiExchange.options">                
</select>
```